# An amusing factorisation of a trivariate polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I noticed the following amusing pattern when playing around in Wolfram Alpha:

> $a(b-c) + b(c-a) + c(a-b) = 0$
>
> $a^2(b-c) + b^2(c-a) + c^2(a-b) = -(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$
>
> $a^3(b-c) + b^3(c-a) + c^3(a-b) = -(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(a+b+c)$
>
> $a^4(b-c) + b^4(c-a) + c^4(a-b) = -(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(a^2+b^2+c^2 + ab+ bc +ca)$
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> $a^n(b-c) + b^n(c-a) + c^n(a-b) = -(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\left(\displaystyle \sum_{i+j+k=n-2} a^ic^jb^k\right)$

I can prove that $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$ is a factor. How do we get the last factor? Is it always irreducible?

Comment: i would try induction if $n$ is a natural number

Comment: There should be negative signs before $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a) \ldots$ on the RHS.

Comment: @NgChungTak: You are right, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Image of Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1rkS.jpg)

For irreducibility plz see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98043/is-complete-homogeneous-symmetric-polynomials-an-irreducibile-element-in-polyno

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks! I did not think of using the determinant.